# jquery find a string in an array with spaces on it

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make this work? I have an space in the third element of my array " John".

take a look: 
http://jsfiddle.net/hyHFT/

```
<style>
  div { color:blue; }
  span { color:red; }
</style>


<div>"John" found at <span></span></div>
<div>4 found at <span></span></div>
<div>"Karl" not found, so <span></span></div>
<script>var arr = [ 4, "  Pete", 8, "  John" ];

$("span:eq(0)").text(jQuery.inArray("John", arr));
$("span:eq(1)").text(jQuery.inArray(4, arr));
$("span:eq(2)").text(jQuery.inArray("Karl", arr));

</script>
```

Comment: Is removing the spaces before you put the string into the array out of the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
var arr = [ 4, "  Pete", 8, "  John" ];
arr = $(arr).map(String.prototype.trim);
...
```

`map` function applies `trim` to every element in the array, and stores its result (the string without spaces) into a new array, in the same position.

Having your array sanitized, you'll find those elements.

Just a sidenote, it will convert the number to a string. Take care of that.

Good luck!

**Edit:**

If you want to keep the original type, use this:

```
$(arr).map(function(key, val) { return (typeof(val) == "string") ? val.trim() : val; })
```

self-explanatory, isn't it?

Comment: `String.prototype.trim` is not available in older browsers.

Comment: Sorry about that.. didn't know :S How older? Anyway, the second option should avoid that. Thanks for the remark.

Comment: It will definitely not work in IE8 and older. Here is a nice table: http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/

Comment: Wow, and I'm still complaining about IE6... The entire browser family seems to be a crap.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you are using jQuery.

You could make a normalised copy of your `Array` with trimmed members.

```
arr = $.map(arr, $.trim);
```

(thanks [Meouw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12161/meouw) and [Felix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling).)

Comment: No need to wrap `$.trim` in a function, just pass it as a reference:
`arr = $.map(arr, $.trim );`

Comment: You probably can just write: `arr = $.map(arr, $.trim);`

Comment: Oh, early in Australia..... very late here in Europe ;) Have a nice day then, I will go to sleep :D

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [`grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) function.

```
jQuery.grep(arr, function(n, i){
    if (jQuery.trim(n) == 'John') $("span:eq(0)").text(i);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array has "  John", but you're checking for "John".  These are obviously different strings.  This works for me:

```
<style>
  div { color:blue; }
  span { color:red; }
</style>

<div>"John" found at <span></span></div>
<div>4 found at <span></span></div>
<div>"Karl" not found, so <span></span></div>
<script>var arr = [ 4, "  Pete", 8, "  John" ];

$("span:eq(0)").text(jQuery.inArray("  John", arr));
$("span:eq(1)").text(jQuery.inArray(4, arr));
$("span:eq(2)").text(jQuery.inArray("Karl", arr));

</script>
```

Or are you wanting to do some sort of fuzzy matching that ignores spaces?

Answer (score 0):

Use a trimmed copy if you want to ignore spaces.  Make sure to only trim strings, else your lookup of `4` will fail:

```
var arr = [ 4, "  Pete", 8, "  John" ];
var trimmedArr = jQuery.map(arr, function(item)
{
    return typeof item == "string" ? jQuery.trim(item) : item;
});

$("span:eq(0)").text(jQuery.inArray("John", trimmedArr));
$("span:eq(1)").text(jQuery.inArray(4, trimmedArr));
$("span:eq(2)").text(jQuery.inArray("Karl", trimmedArr));
```

[This method works (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/9RbZT/).

Answer (score 0):

try not using jQuery, instead iterate through the array manually and use a RegExp. Replace `jQuery.inArray("John", arr)` with `inArray("John", arr)`, and put the following function in your script:

```
function inArray(string, arr){
    var re = RegExp(string, "g");
    for(var i in arr){
        if(arr[i].search(re) != -1){
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```